# Compare list of items to dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
my_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
my_keys = ['three', 'one','ten','one']

solutions = []
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    found = False
    for i in my_keys:
        if i in key:
           solutions.append(value)
           found = True
           break
        if not found:
           solutions.append('Nan')
```

I get this output:

> ['Nan', 1, 'Nan', 'Nan', 'Nan', 'Nan', 3]

but the **expected output is:**

> Output: ['3', '1', 'Nan', '1']

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you wanted to generate the solutions list with respect to the my_keys list.

Try this:

```
my_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
my_keys = ['three', 'one','ten','one']

solutions = []
for key in my_keys:
    if key in my_dict:
        solutions.append(my_dict[key])
    else:
        solutions.append('Nan')

print(solutions)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) that can be done like:

#### Code:

```
solutions = [my_dict.get(k, 'Nan') for k in my_keys]
```

#### Test Code:

```
my_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
my_keys = ['three', 'one', 'ten', 'one']

solutions = [my_dict.get(k, 'Nan') for k in my_keys]
print(solutions)
```

### Results:

```
[3, 1, 'Nan', 1]
```